# Consuming C# COM server from C# client

Tags: c#, com

The examples I have seen on the internet have managed code COM server/unmanaged code client or vice-versa. I was wondering if it is possible to have both COM server and client in C#.

Comment: are you looking for a [COM Interop Sample: .NET Client and COM Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367d22wa.aspx)?

Comment: The IDE has an explicit check to defeat this, it really is rather useless.  So you can't add a reference to the type library.  The only way to fool it is to use late binding with the *dynamic* keyword.  Just don't, there is no point.  Not for testing either, you won't test any detrimental side-effects of the underlying COM interop plumbing.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually the COM server is exposed by a different application package. If I add a reference to the assembly directly, I need to take care of its own dependencies. This is the primary reason I am thinking of doing it the COM way. I do not have much knowledge about it. Would you say I am thinking it the right way?

Comment: Very vague.  But no, helping the CLR to find dependencies is *considerably* worse in COM.   The install directory for the component does not in any way alter the probing path that the CLR uses to find assemblies, the kind of problem that almost always requires using the GAC.  This is an XY question, ask a question about your original problem.